# What does the @ symbol mean in a URL?

Tags: rest

Does the @ symbol have a special meaning in REST URLs?

For example `https://host/students/{id}/@classes`

Comment: No special meaning in the path portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#appendix-A)

```
   pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

which means that it is just another character that can be used in a [path](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) segment.

A local routing implementation might do something clever when it sees a URI with an unescaped [U+0040](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0040) in the path, but to a general purpose HTTP component it is just a letter.

---

Note that in the [authority](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2) element of a URI, U+0040 does have special meaning as a delimter

```
   URI           = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

   hier-part     = "//" authority path-abempty
                 / path-absolute
                 / path-rootless
                 / path-empty

   authority     = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
```